# How does the Repository Pattern Differ from a Simple Data Access Layer?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've been confused by what I've been reading during my research on the repository pattern. I'm wondering if folks are (incorrectly?) using that word when they simply mean a data access layer.

Since "repository" is not found in the index of [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) (GoF), I've turned to [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) (Fowler). Fowler seems pretty clear (page 323) when he states that **clients create a criteria object** and pass it to the repository to get the results. It looks something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Person> Dependents()
    {
        Repository repository = Registry.personRepository();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.equal(Person.BENEFACTOR, this);
        return repository.matching(criteria);
    }
}
```

Is the criteria object what makes the repository a repository? If not, what does? If abstracting the persistence mechanism (and therefore constructing queries) is the goal, in what way does the repository differ from a simpe DAL/ORM call like this:

```
public class PersonLogic
{
    public List<Person> GetDependents()
    {
        IPersonData personData = DependencyContainer.Resolve<IPersonData>();
        return personData.GetDependents();
    }
}
```

To me, the difference looks like this:
* With the repository pattern, the client constructs different criteria objects and calls the Matching() method on it.
* With the simple DAL, clients just call different methods based on what they want.

Is there more to it than this? Are programmers mistakenly using the term "repository" when they really mean DAL?

**EDIT**

David Osborne sent this link to [Persistence Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400058). It states:

> Basically, the Repository pattern just means putting a façade over
>   your persistence system so that you can shield the rest of your
>   application code from having to know how persistence works.

That's really what a data access layer is. It really appears to me that a repository and a DAL are the same thing, and maybe a "true" repository uses the criteria object.

Comment: As far as the Criteria object goes -- again, .NET is magic! (In a good way) -- and IQueryable and Language INtegrated Query kind of fulfill that role for us. -- So while your code might not look like it's passing in a "criteria" object, by using LINQ against an IQueryable collection, you kind of are still passing in that object at the low level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the **"Using the IQueryable interface"** section and beyond at [Extending and Enhancing the Orders and Registrations Bounded Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591579). It provides an insightful and balanced discussion of DAO/Repository implementations.

As subsequently highlighted by Bob Horn, the [Persistence Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd569757.aspx) articles summarises that:

> Basically, the Repository pattern just means putting a façade over your persistence system so that you can shield the rest of your application code from having to know how persistence works.

Comment: Thanks, David. I haven't had a chance to read all of that yet. I think SO likes answers to include a summary of the answer, instead of just pointing to an external link. I do appreciate the pointer though. I'll check it out.

Comment: I appreciate the SO philosophy. However, there are some concepts that are explained much better by others than myself.

Comment: I just read that post and didn't see anywhere in there that explained what made a repository a repository, or how it differs from a typical DAL class. They did show using a "repository" with IQueryable, but that could be done with a DAL class, too. Maybe I'm just missing something... Thanks again.

Comment: I think it highlights that your question is related to two different flavours of what is, in essence, a repository. The document demonstrates the two approaches and their pros and cons. I think there's little difference between a prescriptive repository of a certain type with specific GetBys and a DAO for a specific type.

Comment: This is also a relevant exploration of the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd569757.aspx

Comment: Thank you for that link. I edited my question with what I found from that link. If you want to change your answer to include my edit (if you agree with that), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

In general I agree with author's statements, but I'd like to add some details

Difference between *Repository* and *DAL/ORM* that first not only abstracts the persistence mechanism, but also provides [**collection-like** interface for **accessing domain objects** … and **isolates** domain objects from details of the database access code](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

### Differences

For external layers, such as Business Logic:

- Helps to avoid [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html). External layers depend on *abstraction* of *Repository*, rather than a specific implementation of *DAL/ORM*. Thus you could avoid all infrastructure and logical dependencies while working with *Repository*.
- operates with *domain objects*, rather then a instances of POJO/POCO/DTO
- *CRUD* operations applied to *collection-like interface* provided by *Repository*, rather then specific *DAL/ORM* methods. For example [.net](/questions/tagged/.net): working with collection that implements `IEnumerable`, rather then [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) context or [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate) session

### Similarities

*Repository* contains *DAL/ORM* underneath and serves same purpose

Comment: Thanks, akim. Aren't those first two bullet points the same for the DAL scenario in my question? The BLL asks a dependency container for a data class (avoiding a specific implementation), and it also operates with domain objects. No?

Comment: No. First, I have carefully reread your original question, and found that `PersonData` is more close to [Active Record pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), when object itself encapsulates the database access. In this case _Repository_ is different. There are several questions that could help: is `PersonData` exists at database as row in a table, or it's a domain object that maps to several tables together; if `PersonData` has been updated, will it be persist by itself, or passed _Repository_ or _DAL/ORM_ method to be persisted.

Comment: Second, _Repository_ is an abstraction over _DAL/ORM_, sure that had similarities. Third, try to imagine unittests with abstract _Repository_ or specific _DAL/ORM_ without queries database — here comes power of abstraction!

Comment: So, PersonData should have been IPersonData. I just noticed that and fixed it. PersonData is not a domain entity, it's a data class. Person would be the entity. So, no, the entity doesn't handle the data access.

Comment: I personally agree with both statements that you have mentioned in question: "constructs different criteria" and "call different methods based on what they want". But also see other differences what I had already mentioned in my answer

Comment: In general I agree with your statements, but I'd like to add some details and already did this