# Translate Generic Query of Business Layer to Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, architecture, layer

I am in the middle of rewriting legacy software to .Net and have created a Data Access Layer using Linq 2 SQL that is working pretty well. The database I am working with has over 230 tables and is not something I can really change. The problem I am running into is with the Business Layer. I would like for the developers to be able to query the business objects and have those queries map to the data layer. So something like `Customers.Query(c=>c.ID=="MyID")`
and have that be able to be passed to my DAL, `context.CUSTOMERS.Query(c=>c.UID == "MyID")`
I have generic Query methods in my DAL that will allow me to pass in the DAL query.

This is where I am stuck. I can create a method that uses an Expression but how do I get and then map those fields to the corresponding DAL fields and get the value that is trying to be matched. What I don't want is to have to expose the DAL objects to the end developers who are doing presentation layer stuff. I am open to ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have been able to find a solution to this. Using [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521.aspx) and help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007101/how-can-i-convert-a-lambda-expression-between-different-but-compatible-models)

I modified the VisitMember method:

```
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        string sDbField = ((SFWBusinessAttributes)node.Expression.Type.GetProperty(node.Member.Name).GetCustomAttribu`tes(typeof(SFWBusinessAttributes), true)[0]).DBColumn;
        var expr = Visit(node.Expression);
        if (expr.Type != node.Type)
        {
            MemberInfo newMember = expr.Type.GetMember(sDbField).Single();
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expr, newMember);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
```

To pull the Attribute off of the Property of the Business Object.

To call everything I can do from the app:

```
    BusObj.Query(a => a.IsDeleted != true && a.Company.Contains("Demo"))
```

Which calls a method in the business object

```
    public List<Account> Query(Expression<Func<Account, bool>> expression)
    {
        using (Data.CustomerData data = new Data.CustomerData(_connstring))
        {
             return MapList(data.Query<Data.Database.ACCOUNT>(expression.Convert<Account, Data.Database.ACCOUNT>()).ToList());
        }
```

Performance seems pretty good, I know there is going to be a hit with the mapping but it is something I can live with for now.

Answer (score 0):

Do the developers need to query the business objects using an expression? The reason I ask is because mapping expressions may be complicated. At some point, some mapping has to be done. The DAL is usually the mapping layer that turns DB objects into domain objects, and vice-versa.

Two other approaches to consider:

1. Use the repository pattern, where the caller passes in a query object. The DAL would be responsible for turning that query object into an expression. An example of the repository pattern is shown in a [question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14092234/279516).
2. Expose more specific methods, like:

   public Customer GetCustomersById(int id) { ... }

I believe either of those two approaches would make things easier to query.

Comment: The developers will need to query the objects, there are 230 business objects and creating specific methods for each is not do able, GetById, GetByName, GetByContract...etc. I have the Business objects mapping to the Data Objects through generic mapping methods, the issue is doing a query, how can I intelligently query Business object properties and have those pass to the DAL to retrieve the proper Data. Ideally if I could take this BusLay.Shipments.Query(s=>s.ShipId =="bob") and be able to translate it to the DAL DAL.SHIPMENTS.Find(s=>s.SHIPMENT_ID == "bob"). I could map the results back.

Comment: I have shyed away from the Repository Pattern because it seems like I would be duplicating my Business Layer by creating objects that reflect the objects already created by Linq to Sql so that I can map them to Business layer objects that the Developers will use. Ultimately the Presentation Layer Devs wont even have access to the DAL. They will query the Business Objects to bind to grids and do whatever functions they need to do.

Comment: I gave you a +1 because this is an interesting question. I have a couple of friends that may be able to suggest something. Let me show them your question...