# Ideas regarding the right pattern to use to facilitate any future transition to another DB system?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

We are currently moving fast with MongoDB, but it is still not completely sure whether we will end up using it or another, such as SQL, from various reasons (cost, scalability, latency, environment, ...).

My question is what would be the best pattern to use to facilitate any future change. Is the `Repository pattern` the fittest to this task? any other idea?

We use `C#`, FWIW...

### Edit, question refinement:

The thing with the `Repository` pattern in particular, is that it introduces a fair amount of complexity and some difficulty during refactoring (which will surely come...) due to its loosely-coupled nature - it requires a `DataMapper`, and if I recall correctly, an `ActiveRecord` as well (due to the `DataMapper` I think...).

I don't want to get into a whole debate about design-patterns - the amount of materials about it is endless.

My question is simple - why isn't the following simple pattern better, where both domain-layer and DAL depend on some data-model module?

[image]

Comment: provider pattern may be what you are looking for. it is extensible.  check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx

Comment: Domain model has knowledge about DAL, how will you change your data source then?

Comment: And what is IDataProvider? How should it look in your case? And also, ActiveRecord is another pattern, used in ROR heavily. Has nothing common with repository.

Comment: @Vladislav, `IDataProvider` is the DAL interface. Any DAL must implement it, and the domain must have access to it. Please ignore it... it's not the main issue here...

Answer (score 4):

The [repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14092234/279516) is a pattern that you would use for data access in general, whether that's MongoDB or something else.

If you want to *switch* between the two, then you're talking about good, old-fashioned [polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUOarQzx1Oc), and not necessarily a pattern. The caller shouldn't know or care which data access mechanism is being used.

The way we switch between SQL and MongoDB right now is to use a dependency container to facilitate [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). There are [many options](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) for this out there. Using that approach, you could set which data layer to use in a config file.

The caller to the data layer could look like this:

```
using (var data = DependencyContainer.Resolve<IFooData>())
{
    data.DoSomething()
}
```

The dependency container will return an implementation of IFooData. And the caller won't know (or care) if it's MongoDB or SQL (or whatever).

And the config file could look like this (specifying to use MongoDB in this case):

```
  <DependencyContainerConfiguration BaseClass="MongoDbCacheAccessLayer, Company.Components">
  </DependencyContainerConfiguration>
```

We rolled our own dependency container, so the code above is specific to what we did, but the essence is the same.

Comment: The switch itself is obvious, Ioc, dependency injection... the question is about the `IFooData` part - how its implementers are structured. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Default way of abstracting data source from your application logic is `Repository` pattern.

You could use a generic one with `IQueryable` and expression trees for data operations performed at db level, while your potential data sources have libraries with `IQueryable` implementation as well as current one, otherwise it could be too tricky to change your source without code modifications.

Or you could use multiple business dependent repository classes for your entities, with methods like `GetAllAdminUsers` for data access (I'm overstating, but you should get the idea), it will be simpler to change data source in that case, but will require lines of boilerplate.

Moreover, I don't think that attempt to wrap all possible data sources with single abstraction is a good idea - it will start leaking at some point, because of implementation details. (Not every Linq operator could be supported by queryable provider. Or issues with different fault tolerance approaches could arise)

Comment: See my edit regarding using `Repository`. The `IQueryable` method sounds promising. Would it require `Expression` trees walking and stuff like that (e.g. to transform a `Where(...)` expression to, say, `SQL` queries) ?

Comment: Expression trees will be used to translate your queries, of course. But it's a hard task, so you should not do it manually. Use some libs like entity framework, it's their responsibility.